# LiPo charging circuit

Tags: voltage, current, battery-charging, charger, lipo

I'm using a 6s Lithium Polymer battery in one of my projects, and I'd like to make it more consumer friendly. This means that I should probably get rid of the need for a balance charger (which few consumers have) by including the balancing and charging mechanism in the project then simply have a power adapter plug into the project. However through many google searches I haven't been able to find a correct term for this or even where to get started. My electrical knowledge is fairly basic, so whatever knowledge and or resources that can be offered are greatly appreciated!

Comment: I would advise looking at other battery types as well, especially the lithium-iron-phosphate batteries which are much more stable (see my answer as well) (see the wiki article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithium_iron_phosphate_battery )

Comment: I believe the most common term is battery management system, or BMS. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Try searching for "power management IC" or battery management IC"

From TI: http://www.ti.com/lsds/ti/power-management/battery-management-products-overview.page this looks like what you want.

A word of caution, though: Li-ion batteries (especially big ones, like that 6s you mentioned) have the potential for fires and explosions. If you're going to sell this to a consumer, you **really** want to be sure that it's safe. Judging by your question, you don't seem to have a lot of experience, so might be good to consult with somebody who does.

Is there a reason why you have to have a Li-ion battery? You might also want to take a good look at other battery chemistries, especially the lithium-iron-phosphate batteries: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithium_iron_phosphate_battery

Comment: @faeophyta Water works fine to distinguish Li-*ion* fires, e.g. [see here](http://www.candlepowerforums.com/vb/showthread.php?375616-Class-D-fireextinguisher&p=4326579&viewfull=1#post4326579). Beware that there is much confusion between nonrechargeable Lithium batteries and rechargeable Li-*ion* batteries. The former contain *metallic* Lithium so require special firefighting techniques due to this. The latter do not, since they contain only Lithium *ions*, not metallic Lithium (except possibly in abnormal conditions where very small amounts may plate out)

Comment: @BillDubuque Oops, you're right. I'll fix that. Still not good to see your device go up in flames, though.

Comment: Oops, above should be "extinguish" not "distinguish".